# Filter post and route them on a tab in a facebook page

Tags: facebook, feeds

I use dlvr.it to route feeds from many sites on my facebook page. The problem is that they all appear in my main page, hiding the post I create.

So i was wondering, is there a way to redirect all those post on a separate tab? maybe some kind of filtering based on the content of the post?

Thanks a lot